# Why is it so bad to run a PHP script continuously?

Tags: php, command-line, cron, infinite-loop

I have a map. On this map I want to show live data collected from several tables, some of which have astounding amounts of rows. Needless to say, fetching this information takes a *long* time. Also, pinging is involved. Depending on servers being offline or far away, the collection of this data could vary from 1 to 10 minutes.

I want the map to be snappy and responsive, so I've decided to add a new table to my database containing only the data the map needs. That means I need a background process to update the information in my new table continuously. Cron jobs are of course a possibility, but I want the refreshing of data to happen as soon as the previous interval has completed. And what if the number of offline IP addresses suddenly spike and the loop takes longer to run than the interval of the Cron job?

My own solution is to create an infinite loop in PHP that runs by the command line. This loop would refresh the data for the map into MySQL as well as record other useful data such as loop time and failed attempts at pings etc, then restart after a short pause (a few seconds).

However - I'm being repeatedly told by people that a PHP script running for ever is BAD. After a while it will hog gigabytes of RAM (and other terrible things)

Partly I'm writing this question to confirm if this is in fact the case, but some tips and tricks on how I would go about writing a clean loop that doesn't leak memory (If that is possible) wouldn't go amiss. Opinions on the matter would also be appreciated.

The reply I feel sheds the most light on the issue I will mark as correct.

Comment: An incredibly minor point, but please don't add signatures/sign-offs to questions. (That aside, this is a very well constructed question.) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop should be in one script which will activate/call the actual script as a different process...much like cron is doing.
That way, even if memory leaks, and non collected memory is accumulating, it will/should be free after each cycle.

Comment: I would love an example. Do you mean something like this? http://pastebin.com/SJeq9Xge

Answer (score 2):

> However - I'm being repeatedly told by people that a PHP script running for ever is BAD. After a while it will hog gigabytes of RAM (and other terrible things)

This used to be very true.  Previous versions of PHP had *horrible* [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), so long-running scripts could easily accidentally consume far more memory than they were actually using.  [PHP 5.3 introduced a new garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) that can understand and clean up circular references, the number one cause of "memory leaks."  It's enabled by default.  Check out that link for more info and pretty graphs.

As long as your code takes steps to allow variables to go out of scope at proper times and otherwise unset variables that will no longer be used, your script should not consume unnecessary amounts of memory just because it's PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its bad, as with anything that you want to run continuously you have to be more careful.

There are libraries out there to help you with the task. Have a look at [System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon), which release RC 1 just over a month ago, which allows you to "Set options like max RAM usage".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running an infinite loop I'd be tempted to go with the cron option you mention in conjunction with a database table entry or flat-file that you'd use to store a "currently active" status bit to ensure that you didn't have overlapping processes attempting to run at the same time.

Whilst I realise that this would mean a minor delay before you perform the next iteration, this is probably a better idea anyway as:

1. It'll let the RDBMS perform any pending low-priority updates, etc. that may well been on-hold due to the amount of activity that you've been carrying out.
2. Even if you neatly unset all the temporary variables you've been using, it's still possible that PHP will "leak" memory, although recent improvements (5.2 introduced a new memory management system and garbage collection was overhauled in 5.3) should *hopefully* mean that this less of an issue.

In general, it'll also be easier to deal with other issues (if the DB connection temporarily goes down due to a config change and restart for example) if you use the cron approach, although in an ideal world you'd cater for such eventualities in your code anyway. (That said, the last time I checked, this was far from an ideal world.)

Comment: 1. Wouldn't that also be the case when using infinite loops, as long as there's a pause between each interval? In my case this script will run on a dedicated server anyway. 2. Could that be solved by running one PHP file that when loops, executes another PHP file once, then takes a break?

Comment: @Codemonkey 1. Yes. 2. In theory yes. However, I've still a nagging feeling that it won't be quite as reliable. That said, it would be trivial to convert the approach you mention to use cron after the fact, so this could well be the way to go. (i.e.: Try the PHP script spawning copies of itself in a different "mode" approach and if that's seen to degrade over time then simply call the same script via cron.) As long as you periodically log the results of `memory_get_usage`, `memory_get_peak_usage`, etc. then it should be fairly easy to monitor how things are going.

Answer (score 0):

First I fail to see how you need a daemon script in order to provide the functionality you describe.

> Cron jobs are of course a possibility, but I want the refreshing of data to happen as soon as the previous interval has completed

The neither a cron job nor a daemon are the way to solve the problem (unless the daemon becomes the data sink for the scripts). I'd spawn a dissociated process when the data is available using a locking strategy to aoid concurrency.

Long running PHP scripts are not intrinsically bad - but there reference counting garbage collector does not deal with all possible scenarios for cleaning up memory - but more recent implementations have a more advanced collector which should clean up a lot more (circular reference checker).