# Sending notifications on exact time in future via PHP without using Cron

Tags: php, cron

I have a situation where user defines when he wants his notification to be sent. [image]

What I need to do is to make that happen, but without `Cron job`. I thought something like :

```
 while(true){
     //something that is checking which time is it now and comparing desired time 
    //code for sending notifications(already got it)
   sleep(3)
    }
```

So, infinite loop that is always checking current time and has pause for 3 seconds.I wonder if it is possible doing it like this or is there a better way? I have never done something like this, so please help.

Comment: What you need to do is check if(current time >= your delivery time) then show these notifications

Comment: Depending on which PHP version you are using, this may be fairly processor/memory intensive, especially if you run it once for each user.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372119/why-is-it-so-bad-to-run-a-php-script-continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without cronjobs you could use a PHP class to shedule your tasks. Something like the PHP-Deamon from Shane Harter.
https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon